# The alert dialog box, for the alert stats, at the very end of the code is not popping up after the loop ends

Tags: javascript, alert

Can you guys kindly help me out? I don't know what's wrong with my code. After my loop ends, the alert dialog box at the very end (alert stats) is not popping up. Here's my code: `JavaScript`

```
var location1 = 3;
var location2 = 4;
var location3 = 5;
var guess;
var hits = 0;
var guesses = 0;
var isSunk = false;
while (isSunk == false) {
    guess = prompt("Ready, aim, fire! (Enter a number from 0-6):");
    if (guess < 0 || guess > 6) {
        alert("Please enter a valid cell number!");
    } else {
        guesses = guesses + 1;

        if (guess == location1 || guess == location2 || guess == location3) {
            alert("HIT!");
            hits = hits + 1;
            if (hits == 3) {
                isSunk == true;
                alert("You sank my battleship!");
            }
        } else {
            alert("MISS");
        }
    }
}
var stats = "You took " + guesses + " guesses to sink the battleship, " + "which means your shooting accuracy was " + (3/guesses);
alert(stats);
```

Comment: *"After my loop ends"* - Your debugging is based on a false assumption.  Your loop **doesn't** end.  Instead of assumption, use your browser's debugging to observe the behavior of the code.

Comment: ok, thank you! my carelessness got to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

`isSunk == true;`

Instead of reassigning `isSunk` to `true` you're comparing it to `true`

Change that to:

`isSunk = true;`